# Microsoft Excel Rank add (Tied) to ties not break them

Tags: excel, rank

I have a spreadsheet that ranks my players based on a series of scores. Using the RANK function, I get ties. I want to KEEP these ties intact but I do want to add (tied) to the values if they are tied. For example:

1st

2nd

3rd

4th (tied)

4th (tied)

5th

There are plenty of tutorials online on how to break ties, but I do not want to break them. Just add text to them. Any ideas on how to do this?

Here is a link to the actual document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q77rp8as91BC917SBcWX1sVdrtOyzwGCUwxxSnvXPCQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Perhaps using conditional formatting might be a step in the right direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional formatting. Assume your data is in A1:A7 and your `RANK` functions are in C1:C7. Make a rule for C1:C7:

```
Select a rule type: Use a formula to determine which cells to format
Format values where this formula is true: =COUNTIF($C$1:$C$7,C1)>1
```

[image: conditional format dialog]

Format > Number > Custom

```
0 "(tied)"
```

[image: Number tab on format cells dialog]

and it will look like

[image: Excel range showing conditional formatting applied]

Comment: This works however, I now have a new issue. The tied value now replaces the next in line in your example, we have 1, 2, 3, 4 (tied), 4 (tied), 6, 7 Which is missing 5... I still need 5 to show up.

Comment: I also ran into another problem but less severe. I'm using conditional formatting to make Ordinal Numbers as well. This rule does make (tied) but it removes my Ordinal Suffix from said number so I end up with 1st, 2nd, 3 (tied), 3 (tied), 5th. What I need is 1st, 2nd, 3rd (tied), 3rd (tied), 4th, 5th...

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer even though it doesn't completely solve my issue, mainly because this is special case where I will have the opportunity to use javascript on the same info in the step I would normally be taking after entering this info. I will do the rest of the formatting in Java. Thanks a ton for the help! :)

Comment: @MichaelWhite, normally (in rankings not in Excel) if you have tied values you would skip straight from 4th to 6th. You can learn how to add ordinal suffixes to numbers here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/pro-tip-add-an-ordinal-indicator-to-a-value-in-excel/